# Is there a possibility to receive alerts from a lower timeframe in a Pine Script?

Tags: notifications, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can’t understand if there is a way to, for example, on an hourly time frame, receive notifications about fulfilled conditions at the closes of 15 minute candles.
I can calculate the volume delta at 5 and 15 minutes on the hour via request.security_lower_tf, but I would like to receive confirmation not at the hourly update, but at the 15-minute close.

I tried to do this via request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "15", timeframe.change("15")) and tracking the array size, but the script does not work correctly. Is this even possible?

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

To receive alerts at a lower timeframe, set your chart to the desired lower timeframe with the appropriate conditions and parameter settings and create the alert.

A created alert will always trigger with the conditions you created it with, including chart timeframe, no matter your *current* chart timeframe.

Comment: My calculation of basic data is carried out on an hourly timeframe, connecting data from lower periods and checking conditions would improve entry points, entry conditions and notifications about them would occur before the closing of the hourly candle.
In any case, the main calculation period is 1 hour.

Comment: In that case, calling the higher timeframe data from the lower timeframe will be better.